# Sending DatagramPacket with no internet connection - Android

Tags: java, android, udp

I'm using the following code to send `DatagramPacket` to a given address:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(anIPAddress);

DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(packetBytes, packetBytes.length,
    address, port);

socket.send(packet);
socket.close();
```

It works fine, but how come this code does not throw any `Exception` when there's no internet connection available?

I turn off both Wi-Fi and mobile data, and this code still gets executed without any errors.

Is there a way to ensure that the packet is actually sent?

(i don't care if it's reached the destination or not, i'd just like to make sure it is sent)

Comment: Datagram packets can be sent over localhost. So an Internet connection is not necessary to send Datagram packets.

Comment: Check this out. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/UseDatagramSockettosendoutandreceiveDatagramPacket.htm

Comment: create two java programs. One chatclient and one charserver and watch them communicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();` to check what interfaces are available.
Then you can check with `ni.isUp()`.

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets=NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
for(int i=0; nets.hasMoreElements(); ++i) {
    NetworkInterface ni=nets.nextElement();
    if (ni.isUp() && !ni.getName().equals("lo")) {
        //ni is not local
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect the datagram socket to the destination. Then after a few sends you may get an exception. If the datagram socket isn't connected there's an error routing issue which I cannot remember offhand: I'll edit it in when au get a chance to look it up.

And yes I know UDP is a connectionless protocol. But you can still connect a UDP socket.